# How to access DataGrid in separate class passed from another function

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid

I am creating a separate DataAcessLayer for DB connection/operations in my WPF Application.

I was creating separate function in the class so as to directly pass a Datagrid and select query to bind that datagrid.

It was made as below:

```
 private void FillDataGrid(string sql, DataGrid grd)
        {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
                SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable("Employee");
                sda.Fill(dt);
        }
```

Here i am passing select query and data grid from other class as

```
FillDataGrid("select * from emp",grdEmp);
```

But when i was trying to bind datagrid   `FillDataGrid` function i was not finding:

`grd.Itemsource` in it.

how can i access/bind DataGrid in that function

Comment: It is not a good practice to use data grid in data layer.Best option is to pass your data table to presentation layer and do the filling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Prasanth V J said, you can do like this:

```
public DataTable FillDataGrid(string sql)
    {
        var conn = new SqlConnection("Your connectionString");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("Employee");
        sda.Fill(dt);
        return dt;
    }
```

Then:

```
YourDataGrid.ItemsSource = FillDataGrid("select * from emp").DefaultView;
```